# Linked Datetimepicker not updating if defaultDate is set

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am using datetimepicker with a pair of linked selectors.

Upon the initial load the 'start_date' should show the current date and the 'expiry_date' should show the 'start_date + 30 days. This works as intended. However when a new 'start_date' is selected the expiry should always default to be 30 days ahead.

This is what I have:

```
$(function () {
        function plusCalendarMonthToDate(e) {
            return moment(e.date).add(30, 'days').millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0)
        }
        defaultStartDate = new Date();
        $('#datetimepicker-start').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00',
            minDate: defaultStartDate,
            defaultDate: defaultStartDate
        });
        $('#datetimepicker-expiry').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00',
            minDate: $('#datetimepicker-start').val(),
            defaultDate: plusCalendarMonthToDate(defaultStartDate)
        });
        $("#datetimepicker-start").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker-expiry').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            // when a start_date is selected, set the expiry to 30 days plus
            plusCalendarMonth = plusCalendarMonthToDate(e);
            $('#datetimepicker-expiry').data("DateTimePicker").defaultDate(plusCalendarMonth);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker-expiry").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker-start').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
```

When I select a new start_date the expiry_date does not update. I think it is because I already set the 'defaultDate' in the initialisation, if I remove it then the feature works but when I lose my initial default value for the expiry_date. How can I over-write the initial defaultDate?

Comment: If you're just adding a month to the current date why do you need `defaultStartDate` as a parameter? Wouldn't it make more sense to just instantiate the date in the function then add a month and return it?

Comment: @Mike I'm only adding 30 days to the current date upon first load. Once a start_date is selected 30 days must be added to this too/

Answer (score 0):

Seems the solution is to use 'date()' not 'defaultDate()':

```
$('#datetimepicker-expiry').data("DateTimePicker").date(plusCalendarMonth)
```